# SQL query to a relational algebra

Tags: sql

i need to translate the SQL query to a relational algebra expression.

```
SELECT P.Name 
FROM Players P, Games G
WHERE P.Id =  G.PlayerId
    AND P.Game = 'Football' AND G.Season ='2019'
```

where: Players (Id, Name, Game) Games (PlayerId, GameCode, Season)

Comment: Tip of today: Start with learning modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: Also SO is not a free coding service website.  We expect you to write your own code.  If you're stuck, we'll try to help you.

Comment: π Name (σ Game="Football"∧ Season ="2019"(σ Id = PlayerId(Players ⨝ Games))   it is true ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL query using the JOIN keyword:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Players join Games on Id =  PlayerId
    where Game = 'Football' AND Season ='2019'
```

I used relax calculator available online to form the relational algebra equivalent:

```
pi Name 
    sigma Game = 'Football' AND Season ='2019'  (
        Players ⨝ Id=PlayerId Games
    )
```